# Environment Tag Helper won't work aspnet core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, html-helper

I have the following snippet in a view:

```html
<environment include="fdsfdfds">
    <div class="warning">Testing Environments</div>
</environment>
```

I have the following in my _ViewImports.cshtml file

```cs
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

I have no environment called "fdsfdfds", but the text still shows in my view. I would, of course, expect nothing to be shown in this case.
What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you're missing `@addTagHelpers *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`.

Comment: Yeah - i tried that from another answer. this causes compilation errors in other areas of this project. i fear there maybe be elements working against each other. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You can also opt into individual tag helpers using `@addTagHelpers Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.EnvironmentTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`